# What could be possible reasons that GetWindowRect() returns size which is smaller than actual visible window for a game?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I set game to a borderless window and it becomes full-screen with size `2560x1440`.

Then I get window size:

```
GetWindowRect(hWnd, tSize);
```

And monitor size:

```
Width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
Height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
```

I receive values for a width being `2048` and `1152` for height . Same dimensions in `tSize` and in `Width` and `Height`. Basically system says that's yeah my window is equal to the size of my monitor, which is correct. But values are smaller, which is incorrect.

Same goes for windowed regime, values that I obtain are smaller(incorrect) than visible ones.

I tried other functions, and only time that I got correct dimensions for my monitor was with DirectX.

```
GetAdapterDisplayMode(adapter, &mode)
```

Comment: did you check scaling/dpi scaling ? try set it to 100%...

Comment: DPI scaling is the answer to 99% of such questions

Comment: Your system DPI is set to 125% and your app is not marked as DPI aware, which means Windows reports scaled coordinates to you.

Comment: Check the value at Settings -> Display -> Scale and layout.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but I would guess that your screen is scaled by 125% since the ratio of your actual height and real height is the same as your actual width verse width.